# Android SDK file not found by flutter doctor on Windows

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sdk

Android studio and SDK components are installed.SDK platform tools, build tools are installed. But when flutter doctor run on command prompt. It gives missing sign that Android SDK File not found : C://my/SDK/path/34.0.0/appt.

[image]

flutter doctor -v said that You need to update your SDK custom location ,using flutter config --android-sdk {path} command . Updated . Still it did not resolve issue.I added image of flutter doctor after doing many things.

SDK path is added in Environment variable by ANDROID_HOME . SDK path is present in local properties with syntax sdk dir=//path.Location updated by flutter config command.All licenses of SDK are accepted by flutter android-licenses.
Still doctor is saying Android SDK file not found.Kindly anyone resolve issue.

Comment: I guess you have to download it manually by opening the Android studio -> going to the SDK manager from settings or there is an icon on the top right corner -> Go to the 2nd tab SDK tool and download it.